# how to implement a css star rating with knockout

Tags: javascript, css, arrays, twitter-bootstrap-3, knockout.js

Have a star rating I'm looking to implement, its work in as far the stars can be clicked, the problem I have is when I have multiple sets of stars shown. Whats happening is which ever set of stars is clicked it effects the other set, only on changing the amount clicked. If I've not explained that very well, say I have 3 sets of stars, I go to the first set and give this a 5 star rating, its holds this value (all good), however if go to the next set of stars and give this the value of say 2, this second set will hold the value of 2 stars however the set above gets set to none. Its like the checked event is not unique for each set and resetting another set. I'm using bootstrap and Knockout js for this, am trying to give a unique ID in the hope that may solve it but no luck. Anyone able to help with this?

Code below, I have skipped a bit of the knockout code that creates my observable array, I have this working as I get a set of stars for each of my feedbackToBeLeft array

```
<style>
.star-rating {
    font-size: 0;
}

.star-rating__wrap {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 16px;
}

    .star-rating__wrap:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        clear: both;
    }

.star-rating__ico {
    float: right;
    padding-left: 2px;
    cursor: pointer;
    color: #9933cc;
}

    .star-rating__ico:last-child {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

.star-rating__input {
    display: none;
}

    .star-rating__ico:hover:before,
    .star-rating__ico:hover ~ .star-rating__ico:before,
    .star-rating__input:checked ~ .star-rating__ico:before {
        content: "\f005";
    }
```

```
<div data-bind="foreach: feedbackToBeLeft"><table style="background-color:transparent;border:none;">
                                <tr>
                                    <td style="width:100px;">
                                        Rating
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="star-rating" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star_' + bookingGuid }">
                                            <div class="star-rating__wrap" data-bind="attr: { id: 'wrap_' + bookingGuid }">
                                                <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star5_' + bookingGuid }" type="radio" name="rating" value="5">
                                                <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: 'star5_' + bookingGuid }" title="Amazing"></label>
                                                <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star4_' + bookingGuid }" type="radio" name="rating" value="4">
                                                <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: 'star4_' + bookingGuid }" title="Good"></label>
                                                <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star3_' + bookingGuid }" type="radio" name="rating" value="3">
                                                <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: 'star3_' + bookingGuid }" title="Ok"></label>
                                                <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star2_' + bookingGuid }" type="radio" name="rating" value="2">
                                                <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: 'star2_' + bookingGuid }" title="Not good"></label>
                                                <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star1_' + bookingGuid }" type="radio" name="rating" value="1">
                                                <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: 'star1_' + bookingGuid }" title="Bad"></label>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            </table></div>
```

Comment: You need unique `id` and `for` and `name` for two set of ratting, If you need ill provide a snippet

Comment: In your above example i didn't see a unique `name` for set 2 rating stars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I would have approached what you are trying to do.

```js
var ratings = [{
    name: 'Bad',
    value: 1
  },
  {
    name: 'Not Good',
    value: 2
  },
  {
    name: 'Ok',
    value: 3
  },
  {
    name: 'Good',
    value: 4
  },
  {
    name: 'Amazing',
    value: 5
  },
];

var data = [{
  bookingGuid: '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111',
  bookingName: 'Room 1',
  ratingValue: 4
}, {
  bookingGuid: '22222222-2222-2222-2222-222222222222',
  bookingName: 'Room 2',
  ratingValue: 2
}];

function StarRatingVm(id, title, value) {
  var self = this;
  self.id = id;
  self.value = value;
  self.title = title;
  self.groupName = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return 'star_' + self.id;
  });
  self.name = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return 'star' + self.value + '_' + self.id;
  });
}


function Vm() {
  var self = this;

  var mappedData = data.map(function(item) {
    item.availableRatings = createRatings(item.bookingGuid, ratings);
    item.selectedValue = ko.observableArray();
    return item;
  })

  self.feedbackToBeLeft = ko.observableArray(mappedData);



  function createRatings(id, ratings) {
    return ratings.map(function(item) {
      return new StarRatingVm(id, item.name, item.value);
    });
  }

}
var vm = new Vm();
window.vm = vm;
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>
<div data-bind="foreach: {data: feedbackToBeLeft, as: 'feedback'}">
  <table style="background-color:transparent;border:none;">
    <tr>
      <td style="width:100px;">
        Rating <span data-bind="text: feedback.bookingName"></span>
      </td>
      <td>
        <div class="star-rating" data-bind="attr: { id: 'star_' + bookingGuid }">
          <div class="star-rating__wrap" data-bind="attr: { id: 'wrap_' + bookingGuid }, foreach: { data: availableRatings, as : 'rating'}">
            <input class="star-rating__input" data-bind="checkedValue: rating, checked: feedback.selectedValue, attr: { id: rating.name, name: rating.groupName, title: rating.title } " type="radio">
            <label class="star-rating__ico fa fa-star-o fa-lg" data-bind="attr: { for: rating.name, title: rating.title }"></label>
          </div>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>

<br/>

<ul data-bind="foreach: feedbackToBeLeft">
  <li><span data-bind="text: bookingName"></span>  Rating: <span data-bind="text: selectedValue().value"></span> stars</li>
</ul>

<pre data-bind="text: ko.toJSON(vm)"></pre>
```

Comment: great example many thanks, I need the font awesome stars really, my example has something to do with the css and the before and after attributes. I've no idea how to manipulate these correctly, just going to start again with the whole darn thing :(